# Is Raktavija's fight with Shiva ever mentioned in any scripture?

Tags: shiva, scripture, kali

I have always heard about Raktavija and his fight with Durga and Kali and how he is annihilated. But during my visit to Elephanta caves, a tourist guide was telling a different version of story by replacing Kali with Shiva. Is this version of Shiva killing Raktavija is mentioned in any hindu scripture?

Comment: The Elephanta caves talk about Andhaka who also had the same boon as Raktabija.

Comment: @Surya ohh, that means that tourist guide made a big mistake, i think you can still answer it.

Comment: I'll answer once I find the reference. If I am write it us somewhere in the Matsya Purana.

Comment: @Surya [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andhaka) says  Matsya Purana, Kurma Purana, Linga Purana and Shiva Purana

Comment: @AnkitSharma you should edit your question, i can also edit but it's depend on you Cause Raktavija also fought with lord shiva but Mahadevi Shakti Killed Raktavija After a long period of the war but you are mentioning that lord shiva killed Raktvija but The Elephanta caves talk about Aandhaka who got same boon.

Comment: @EshanSingh I am talking about what tourist guide told me, you can mention in answer that tourist guide is wrong and how with citation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The Elephanta caves talk about Andhaka who also had the same boon as RaktaVija.*

Here is the [Sources](http://elephanta.co.in/mythical-themes-at-elephanta) [image]

> **Andhakasura Vadha Murthi**

[Slaying of Andhakasura](http://elephanta.co.in/anhdakasura-vadha-at-elephanta)  : Depicting Shiva slaying a demon called Andhaka. One of the most animated panels in Elephanta. Shiva is represented with eight arms in this panel.

[Here](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/shivapuranam16.html) is mentioned in Shiva Purana How Lord Shankara Killed Andhka and Lifted there bloodless body into Shivaganga

> *The Danava Guru who kept on reciting Om Namah Sivaya Mantra as a gesture of his regret, Siva released the Danava Guru from His semen. **Then Siva applied His Trident to kill Andhaka but for each drop of blood, there was another Andhaka born; Maha Deva ordered Devi Chandika to suck each drop of blood and expanded her tongue for till the Demon’s body was drenched out of blood. Later on Siva lifted the bloodless body of Andhaka**, but the Demon prayed to Siva to admit him among the Sivaganas after death.*